# jQuery: prevent multiple firing fadeOut or any animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on Item1, replace the label "Item1" with "Saved", then fade out the button after 500ms and place back the label "Item1" (saved in var currentText)

If I click the button multiple times it fires too many times. How can I prevent that?

```
$('body').on('click', ".item", function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('Saved!').delay(500).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).text(currentText).css('display', '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved with a simple flag indicating that you are in the process of fading it out.

```
var isFadingOut = false;
$('body').on('click', ".item", function() {
    if (isFadingOut) {
        return;
    }

    isFadingOut = true;
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('Saved!').delay(500).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).text(currentText).css('display', '');
        isFadingOut = false;
    });
});
```

Note: this solution works globally. So if you have multiple different buttons on screen that you want to be able to fade out simultaneously, this will not work. If that's the case, something more like what @Phiter wrote would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', ".item", function() {
    if ($(this).data('off')) return;

    $(this).data('off', true);
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('Saved!').delay(500).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).text(currentText).css('display', '');
        $(this).data('off', false);
    });
});
```

The function will not execute while the button has the `off` data. Kinda like Mike's answer but without the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `not(':animated')`. The `:animated` pseudo selector is used internally by jQuery and is only active when an animation is in progress

```
$('body').on('click', ".item", function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    $(this).not(':animated').text('Saved!').delay(500).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).text(currentText).css('display', '');
    });
});
```